# How to add the item_ID value next to item_SKU value at Admin view order for items ordered block?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid

By default **Magento 2.1.6** shows the item description and the item_SKU , but I also want to add/show the item_ID field to it's first column. Any idea how to add it?

Answer (score -1):

create an function in block.
call that function in phtml get the data and display it in PDP page.

Comment: did you just suggest a core edit?

Comment: nope need to override the core module....